# Problemas com @font-face da mesma família

Tags: css, css3, css-font-face

Estou tendo um problema em relação ao modulo Font do CSS3.

Tenho uma fonte com 3 tipos: **bold, normal e italic** e as inseri no CSS com o mesmo nome porem com os atributos referentes ao font-weight e style relativos a cada tipo. O problema é que em alguns navegadores (Firefox e o Safari do iOS) não leem as fontes diferentes (bold e italic), considerando apenas a default. O firefox chega até a tentar “simular um bold” pela fonte original, mas fica péssimo.

Gostaria de saber se alguem consegue me ajudar com isso **sem utilizar fontes diferentes para cada tipo, colocando por exemplo: GudeaBold, GudeaItalic.**

Abaixo segue o código.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gudea";
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: "normal";
    font-style: "italic"
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Gudea";
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: "bold";
    font-style: "normal"
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Gudea";
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: "normal";
    font-style: "normal"
}
```

Comment: Pelo [exemplo do Google Fonts](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:400,100,100italic,400italic) não parece ter algum erro no seu código.

Comment: Tem como mostrar um exemplo funcional no jsfiddle?

Comment: Pra quem não conhece: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 5):

Para consertar o problema foi simples. 
 Quando não se especifica o peso da fonte, o navegador trata de simula-lo, por isso gerou fontes de tamanhos diferentes. O que fiz foi no lugar de colocar **bold** o **peso** da respectiva fonte. No caso ficaria assim:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gudea";
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/Gudea-Italic-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: "italic"
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Gudea";
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/Gudea-Bold-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: "normal"
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Gudea";
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/Gudea-Regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: "normal"
}
```

E na hora de citar a fonte colocar o peso dela, por exemplo:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Gudea';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Credito ao [Gustavo Rodrigues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2804/gustavo-rodrigues) que deixou o link do [Google Fonts](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:400,100,100italic,400italic) contendo exemplo corretamente aplicado. 
Obrigado!